# Looking for a regular expression to capture occurrences of a pattern and replace each instance with a different value in R

Tags: r, regex

I would like to find every occurrence of a string in a large body of text and replace the nth occurrence of that string with the nth element in an array of replacement strings.

I have a large text file of XML with the url/path of a particular image. This url occurs 1000 times in this file. I have an array of 1000 unique image paths that I would like to substitute into this text file.

The basic idea is: 
needle: IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH
haystack: random XML..src=IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH...random XML... src=IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH... random XML... src=IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH...

Array of image url paths: replaceArray = {IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH, IM_31DS439u38, IM_8939cSd9321,...}

Goal: Replace first occurrence of IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH with the first element of replaceArray, replace the second occurrence of IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH with the second element of replaceArray, etc.

Desired output:
random XML..src=IM_5sWQ4n0fUWh0jVH...random XML... src=IM_31DS439u38... random XML... src=IM_8939cSd9321...

Does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this preferably in R? I've looked around the web a bit but haven't found the answer so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sub` in a loop.
With `sub` you can search and replace the first instance of a pattern.
(In general gsub is more useful, since it replaces all instances.)

[Replacing Regex Matches in String Vectors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

> The sub function has three required parameters: a string with the
>   regular expression, a string with the replacement text, and the input
>   vector. sub returns a new vector with the same length as the input
>   vector. If a regex match could be found in a string element, it is
>   replaced with the replacement text. Only the first match in each
>   string element is replaced. If no matches could be found in some
>   strings, those are copied into the result vector unchanged.

```
df <- c("16_24cat 16_24cat", "25_34cat34343", "35_44cats 16_24cat33 16_24cat", "45_54Cat 16_24cat", "55_104fat")
ar <- c("mouse", "bear", "duck")  
x <- 1
while(x < 5) {
  df = sub(pattern = "cat", replacement = ar[x], df, ignore.case = TRUE,  perl=TRUE);
  x <- x+1;
}
df
```

Output:

"16_24mouse 16_24bear"
"25_34mouse34343"
"35_44mouses 16_24bear33 16_24duck"
"45_54mouse 16_24bear"
"55_104fat"